# How to use different factorlevels as several variables in dataframe

Tags: r

[image: dataset]

This is  my data. I want to have the variables TOTAL with the correspondant values as well as the variable Y25-74 with the correspondant values instead of the variable values where both factor levels are mixed.
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. Include a proper [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself. Explicitly show the desired output you want so possible solutions can be tested.

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow take a tour Go through [How to Ask on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which helps you for more views and some Answers

Comment: More the point: this is a site where people help people *who have code that is not working*. Just asking for people to write your code from scratch with no effort on your part is disrespectful.

Comment: Sorry I really did not want to treat anyone disrespectful. I have read several cheatsheet and just do not know where to start in order to transform the data in the way I need it. I will reformulate my question of course.